# Perfect Matching in a non-bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I need to find out if you can have a perfect matching in a given graph, with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges and $1\leq n,m\leq 100$. I want a complexity of $O(n)$ if possible. I only need to know if there is such a perfect matching, not its composition.

Comment: Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Comment: You want a complexity of $O(n)$ for a tiny problem with only $100$ edges?  That's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the bounds on [the wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) An *existence* algorithm is given [here,](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f04/www/scribes/lec3.pdf) but I don't know how much that buys you.

Comment: I know, I just wonder if there is a better one for just finding if there exists. Is there a property of a graph wich only happens if a graph has a perfect matching?

Comment: Well, those bounds _are_ subcubic...

Comment: See the edit for more.

Answer (score 0):

[Edmonds matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm) runs in $O(n^4)$. It is relatively easy to understand (I think). The Wikipedia page says that the paper 'An $O(V^{1/2}E)$ algorithm for finding maximum matching in general graphs' can do it in $O(\sqrt VE)$, but since (usually) $E=O(V^2)$, it is about $O(V^{\frac 52})$. I can't find that article on google right now. When I find it, I'll post a link. [Here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0032060) is a paid one.
**EDIT:** And [this](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vazirani/Theory-of-matching.pdf) seems to be a free version.

To know whether or not a perfect matching exists is usually just as hard as finding one. If you know your graph is $K_n$ or some other strong fact about it, it may be easy to prove. Otherwise, you will have to search for one.